# How to receive Base64 string with Django REST API

Tags: python, django, opencv, django-rest-framework, base64

I'm trying to receive an image as a base64 string through Django REST API and use it in my OpenCV image recognition program

I've written up a program but it doesnt seem to be working at all

views.py

```
class ImageRecog(generics.ListAPIView):  # API to query uploads
serializer_class = ImageDBSerializer
lookup_field = 'image_tags'

def get_queryset(self):

    image_encoded = self.request.query_params.get('image')

    fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
    fh.write(image_encoded.decode('base64'))
    fh.close()
    # location of the photo we want to test out
    original = cv2.imread(r"imageToSave.png")
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
    index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
    search_params = dict()
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    # Load all the images
    all_images_to_compare = []
    titles = []
    # location of all the photos
    # image store directory
    for f in glob.iglob(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\django\StudyHome\studybuddy\*"): #directory of where images gets gaved from database
        image = cv2.imread(f)
        titles.append(f)
        all_images_to_compare.append(image)

    # 1) Check if 2 images are equals
    for image_to_compare, title in zip(all_images_to_compare, titles):
        if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
            difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
            b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)
            if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
                print("Similarity: 100% (equal size and channels)")
                print("Title: " + title)
                return ImageDB.objects.filter(title__iexact=title)
                break
```

urls.py

```
url('^image/$', ImageRecog.as_view()),  # Upload search Api
```

serializers.py

```
class ImageDBSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ImageDB
    fields = ('image_id', 'image', 'image_tags',)
```

Comment: what is it that is not working

Comment: Does it throw any errors?

Comment: Your logic seems to be in the wrong method. `get_queryset` is not supposed to process or save anything. it's just supposed to return the queryset. From your code, it could end up not returning anything. And using break statement after return? You have a lot of refactoring to do

Comment: @Stephen if i pass a base 64 string it says that string does not have a decode attribute 
imagetosave gets created but api gets attribute error

Comment: @NancyMooree  if i pass a base 64 string it says that string does not have a decode attribute 
imagetosave gets created but api gets attribute error

Comment: @Ken4scholars I've just recently started learning python and Django so I'm very unfamiliar with this, any suggestions as to how i can make it work?

Comment: @pfn then explain what you want to achieve because I can't make out much from your code.

Comment: @Ken4scholars if i put a base 64 string into this, it gets an attribute error which says that string does not have a decode attribute however imagetosave gets created in my media directory